# One-Time-Signature based codes

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography

I'm trying to understand the sentence in bold, in the follow paragraph of [A new one-time signature scheme from syndrome decoding](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/017.pdf)

> Keygen: Given a security parameter $\lambda$, choose a suitable integers $k, n, r, u, w$ such that the actual difficulty of the SDP$(n,r,u)$ meets the level $2^{\lambda}$, with $u\leq w$.
>
> The private key is a generator matrix $P\xleftarrow{$} \mathbb{F}_2^{k\times n}$  of a random $[n,k]$-code whose codewords have weight not exceeding $w$. This weight limit holds in particular for the rows of $P$. **If each bit out of the $w$ bound is chosen uniformly from $\mathbb{F}_2$**, the weight of each row of $P$ follows, by the central limit theorem, a normal distribution with ...

Could you give me some example of a bit out of the $w$ bound, please?